How can I see which Vim version is being used when a file is open?
I have both Vim and Neovim installed. Sometimes, when I run git commit, Vim is opened to edit the commit message, but I'm not sure if Vim has been opened, or Neovim has been opened. I know I can see a Vim's version number by running vim --version or by looking at the information displayed when opening vim with no file, but how do I see the version number when I already have a file open?

Or you could free up your mind by telling Git which editor to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2596835/546861

Why does it matter at all whether it's Vim or Neovim? It should be possible to pull off something like "Fix bug #1234" without extensive plugin support and tons of custom mappings.


I know I can see a Vim's version number [...] by looking at the information displayed when opening vim with no file, but how do I see the version number when I already have a file open?

The :intro command will show exactly that.
It's more concise (and much less detailed) than :version. If Vim flavor and version number are the only items you care about, :intro will suffice.

Type :version or :ve for short, and then enter.
